# Keras and Sklearn logreg returning different results

Tags: scikit-learn, keras, logistic-regression

I'm comparing the results of a logistic regressor written in Keras to the default Sklearn Logreg. My input is one-dimensional. My output has two classes and I'm interested in the probability that the output belongs to the class 1.

I'm expecting the results to be almost identical, but they are not even close.

Here is how I generate my random data. Note that X_train, X_test are still vectors, I'm just using capital letters because I'm used to it. Also there is no need for scaling in this case.

```
X = np.linspace(0, 1, 10000)
y = np.random.sample(X.shape)
y = np.where(y<X, 1, 0)
```

Here's cumsum of y plotted over X. Doing a regression here is not rocket science.

[image: here's y plotted over x]

I do a standard train-test-split:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1,1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1,1)
```

Next, I train a default logistic regressor:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
sk_lr = LogisticRegression()
sk_lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
sklearn_logreg_result = sk_lr.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
```

And a logistic regressor that I write in Keras:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
keras_lr = Sequential()
keras_lr.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', input_dim=1))
keras_lr.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
_ = keras_lr.fit(X_train, y_train, verbose=0)
keras_lr_result = keras_lr.predict(X_test)[:,0]
```

And a hand-made solution:

```
pearson_corr = np.corrcoef(X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],), y_train)[0,1]
b = pearson_corr * np.std(y_train) / np.std(X_train)
a = np.mean(y_train) - b * np.mean(X_train)
handmade_result = (a + b * X_test)[:,0]
```

I expect all three to deliver similar results, but here is what happens. This is a reliability diagram using 100 bins.

[image]

I have played around with loss functions and other parameters, but the Keras logreg stays roughly like this. What might be causing the problem here?

edit: Using binary crossentropy is not the solution here, as shown by this plot (note that the input data has changed between the two plots).

[image]

Comment: Can you try increasing the number of epochs? _ = keras_lr.fit(X_train, y_train,nb_epoch=300 verbose=0) for example. Or _ = keras_lr.fit(X_train, y_train,epochs=300 verbose=0) if using keras 2

Comment: The sklearn solution on average reaches an accuracy of 0.76. The keras solution has, on average an accuracy of 0.75 after ten epochs. It doesn't improve with an increased number of epochs.

Comment: @maz I take the above comment back. You're right, performance does improve. Why is it that the Logreg needs so many epochs in such a simple setting? I have no intuition whatsoever.

If you put the epoch-number as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both implementations are a form of Logistic Regression there's quite a few differences. While both solutions converge to a comparable minimum (0.75/0.76 ACC) they are not identical.

1. Optimizer - keras uses vanille SGD where sklearn's LR is based on
   [liblinear](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/liblinear.pdf) which implements [trust region Newton method](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/logistic.pdf)
2. Regularization - sklearn has built in L2 regularization
3. Weights -The weights are randomly initialized and probably sampled from a different distribution.

Comment: Relevant article to get same results (Accuracy and F1-Score) using Keras and SKLearn: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/build-lookalike-logistic-regression-model-with-sklearn-and-keras-2b03c540cdd5.